# Wix RegistrySearch can read not from all keys under HKLM

Tags: wix, registry, windows-installer

Why in Wix RegistrySearch it is possible to read from  **HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\test** key,
 but it is not possible to read from
**HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\test** key?

Answer (score 1):

The RegistrySearch element authors rows in the [AppSearch Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367578(v=vs.85).aspx) and the [RegLocator Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371171(v=vs.85).aspx) of the MSI database.  These rows are processed by the [AppSearch Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367578(v=vs.85).aspx).   Essentially the AppSearch action uses this information to perform a registry get value operation and assign the result to the property.

Here's several things to consider:

1) Log the installer and read the log file.  If AppSearch fails you'll see an error code in the log.  This will tell you what to look for. Possibilities are:

2) 64 bit Windows has a 64bit and a 32bit registry hive.  Be sure you understand the implications of this.  A 32bit MSI reading HKLM\SOFTWARE... will really be reading from HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node...

3) Registry keys can have ACLs applied to them.  If the user running the install doesn't have rights, MSI won't be able to read it.  Being able to circumvent this would be a security hole.